# URL not changing dynamically through History object

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am trying out this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that when I click a `p`, the URL's path will change to `bar.html`. I am trying this file out from my desktop, so the URL looks something like `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Cupidvogel/Desktop/hist.html`. However nothing happens when I click a `p`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Firefox 5. Error as shown in Firebug console?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this as a local file and it didn't work, but when I tried it on my local webserver it worked fine. I guess you can't use pushState in a local document.

Comment: Okay I will try it. In the meantime you can try it at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide, it's not working.